Optimise audio config for speech to text
I am trying to extract a timecoded transcription from an audio file that i extracted from a transcoded video, the following is the sequence of this (i am using GCP services)

Upload a video to cloud storage
Transcode the uploaded video into several video and audio settings
Transcribe the audio from #2 using the speech-to-text api

All of is working fine, with a so so transcription accuracy. Now, there's an article on the speech-to-text documentation page on how to optimise audio file for speech-to-text, but i can't seem to find the correct config for the audio to set on my transcode audio config.
The following are my transcoding config for audios
import type { google } from '@google-cloud/video-transcoder/build/protos/protos'


export const config: google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1.IJobConfig = {
  elementaryStreams: [
    ...
    {
      key: 'audio-stream0',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac',
        bitrateBps: 32000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream1',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac',
        bitrateBps: 64000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream2',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac',
        bitrateBps: 96000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream3',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac',
        bitrateBps: 128000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream4',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac-he',
        bitrateBps: 128000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream5',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac-he-v2',
        bitrateBps: 128000,
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'audio-stream6',
      audioStream: {
        codec: 'aac',
        bitrateBps: 128000,
        sampleRateHertz: 44100,
      },
    },
  ],
  muxStreams: [
    ...
    {
      key: 'aac-32000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream0',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-64000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream1',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-96000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream2',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-128000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream3',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-he-128000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream4',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-he-v2-128000',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream5',
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'aac-128000-44100',
      container: 'fmp4',
      elementaryStreams: [
        'audio-stream6',
      ],
    },
  ],
  manifests: [
    {
      fileName: 'manifest.mpd',
      type: 'DASH',
      muxStreams: [
        'aac-he-v2-128000',
        'aac-he-128000',
        'aac-128000',
        'aac-96000',
        'aac-64000',
        'aac-32000',
        'aac-128000-44100',
      ],
    },
  ],
}

And here's my speech-to-text operation config
const [operation] = await client.v1.longRunningRecognize({
  config: {
    encoding: 'LINEAR16', //tried MP3 too
    sampleRateHertz: 48000, //tried 16000, 44100 too
    languageCode: lang,
    audioChannelCount: 2,
    alternativeLanguageCodes: ['en'],
    enableWordConfidence: true,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    useEnhanced: true,
    enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
    enableSpokenPunctuation: {
      value: true,
    },
  },
  audio: {
    uri: `gs://${process.env.GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET}/${key}`,
  },
})

I have tried a bunch of combination for the transcoding audio config (like; bitrateBps, and sampleRateHertz), as well as the speech-to-text operation config (like; sampleRateHertz, and encoding), with the best thing i can get is a 70-75% accuracy on the transcription.
I am shooting in the dark here, since i don't really know the details on audio technicality. Is there any optimised transcoding config and transcription config combination that can come up with a better transcription accuracy?

Hi,
You can use the model adaptation feature to help Speech-to-Text recognize specific words or phrases more frequently than other options that might otherwise be suggested.
Model adaptation is particularly helpful in better transcription accuracy.
Please refer to the document for more information.
